# Prevent AWS ELB from setting x-forwarded-proto

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

I have the following setup:

1. Public facing ELB, sends request to ->
2. Nginx instance, sends request to ->
3. internal ELB, sends request to ->
4. node server

I'm trying to switch to Application ELBs because of its advantages over classic ELBs, but it only supports HTTP/HTTPS handlers, not TCP like I was using before, and when using App ELBs #3 seems to overwrite the `x-forwarded-proto` header being set by Nginx in #2.

My node server in #4 is what performs 301 redirects for enforcing https (since we also do path redirection in node, we do protocol redirection in node at the same time in order to shorten our redirect chains).

Is there a way to prevent the ELB in #3 from setting `x-forwarded-proto`?

Comment: Did you find a better way to do it or is your workaround still in place. Also facing the same issue.

Comment: I'm still using the workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, or at least not yet. X-Forwarded-Proto and X-Forwarded-For headers are added by design for all HTTP/S listeners.

Comment: Any idea why that is ? Isn't it a common scenario for backend apps (sitting behind the internal ELB) to depend on x-forward headers that resolve to the public facing ELB (redirects, generating an absolute url for the client, ....)

Answer (score 0):

Note: I added a workaround by setting `x-forwarded-proto-original` in Nginx, then in node using `x-forwarded-proto-original` to overwrite `x-forwarded-proto`.